# Removing Armature and Keeping pose

Tags: armature

I am trying to 3d print some miniatures. I have the Armature all posed, and now I want to remove the armature, but keep the pose.

This will hopefully allow me to break up the model into arms/legs/torso for easier printing. I plan on doing some Booleans to the intersecting parts but I cant remove the armature without also losing the pose.

Here is the file: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=43373

Answer (score 8):

Just ***apply*** the *Armature Modifier* for every loose part of your model. Then delete the armature. Before that I recommend you to *apply transformations* to all the parts (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>).
[image]

I noticed, that legs mesh has multiple users and the error occurs. Go to *Object Data* header and click the ***'2'*** button to make it a single user.
[image]
[image]

I've noticed, that after applying the *Armature Modifier* for the knife an error accured. I just deleted the modifier and everything works okay, but this is is the first time I see this kind of error. I've got no idea how to fix it (I should ask a question about it).
[image]

After applying *Armature Modifier* to every part of your model you may delete the bones.
Cool model BTW :).

Comment: oh thanks, silly mistake by me. I actually pulled the model from Starcaft2 and posed it up myself, so some of the weirdness could have come from that conversion.

Comment: Here's how to fix 'Modifier is disabled, skipping apply' error: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62301/how-to-fix-modifier-is-disabled-skipping-apply-error

Comment: Did you delete this while editing, then undelete? It wasn't here when I posted mine, but still it's older than mine.

Comment: The modifier on the knife is disabled, because it doesn't have an armature. You get the same error with e.g. a shrinkwrap without a target or a subsurf with **0** subdivisions.

Comment: @Duane Dibbley Yes, I deleted and then undeleted my answer. Thanks for a tip about other error cases. Though I use Blender for a long time I see this kind of issue for the first time. It's never late to learn :).

Comment: I only knew it because I've made that silly mistake on more than one occasion. Obviously you haven't. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The legs/biceps object shares some data with some other object. First make it single user. In Object mode, press <kbd>U</kbd> (Unlink) followed by <kbd>D</kbd> (Object & Data). This was the one I found that had linked data, but if there are more, do the same with each of them.

[image]

Once this is done, go to the modifiers panel and click Apply in the Armature modifier. Do this with each object that's rigged.

[image]

Now you can safely delete the armature.