# How to fix 'Modifier is disabled, skipping apply' error?

Tags: modifiers, armature, edit-mode

I've tried to answer this question: [Removing Armature and Keeping pose](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62295/removing-armature-and-keeping-pose) and apply the *Armature Modifier*, when suddenly the  ***'Modifier is disabled, skipping apply'*** error window appeared. How to fix it, so I may apply the modifier? 
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without proper settings a modifier is "disabled" as it can't perform it's task. To enable a modifier, suitable options need to be chosen - for the armature modifier that is assigning an armature to it.

[image: armature modifier]

Given that the modifier is not doing anything you could also delete it without effect.

Answer (score 2):

Check if your viewport is set to 0. Just turn it up to see the effect of the modifier.
This worked for me for Subdivision surface modifier

Comment: I had this problem with the SubSur but not lucky. My solution was to copy the object and armature to another file and the SubSur worked. Mysterious...

Comment: That was the ticket for me.   Subsurf modifier can't work if Viewport Max Subdivision is set to 0.

Render > Simplify > Viewport > Max Subdivision