# Having trouble applying Modifiers to my object

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface

having trouble applying modifiers to my object, it tells me its "disabled and skipping apply".
Anyone know how to fix this? -Thanks

Comment: This sounds similar to:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62301/how-to-fix-modifier-is-disabled-skipping-apply-error

Comment: I agree with @HeziShahmoon on this. Since you provide no information which modifier you have problems with and how its settings are, anything else would be blind guessing. Let's say you have a _Subdivision Surface_ modifier, with a subdivision level set to 0. In this case there is nothing to apply, because the modifier doesn't modify anything. Applying it would give the same result as simply removing it from the object.

Comment: Are you in object mode?

Comment: One other thought if you haven't sorted it by now: Click the green Mesh Data triangle on the properties panel and see if there's a number at the right-hand end of the Object's name field next to the shield icon. If there is, click it to make the object single-user and you should then be able to apply the modifier.

Comment: Apoligies, I thought I had added it in there somewhere, I am trying to apply the shrinkwrap modifier to the frosting of that tutorial donut on youtube. I am not in object mode and other modifiers apply, does this help? @GordonBrinkmann

Comment: @Wesley As Hezi and I wrote before, what are the settings of the modifier? If it's not really doing anything it will not be applied because it would have no effect.

Comment: Holy smokes i understand what you mean I found out I had not selected on the mod what to shrinkwrap to, being the donut. I appreciate the help in the feedback immensely, thank you. @GordonBrinkmann